# ¿Cómo selecciono un divY y selecciono otro divX, retornando los valores del divY?

Tags: javascript

lo que pasa es que tengo varios divs que se forman por un ciclo for y que al final los selecciono con un this, cambiandole el css, pero lo que hace es que me lo selecciona y me deja el div anterior con ese valor:

```js
for(var i=0;i<resultado.length;i++){

                       
    var template=`
    
    <div class='divConValores'>
       
            <div class=''>Valores:</div> 
            <div class=''>`+valores[i]+`</div>

     
    </div>`
}

    caja.html(template);

    $('.divConValores').click(function(){
       
        $(this).css('display','none');

        var valorSeleccionado=$(this);
        if(valorSeleccionado){ 
            
            valorSeleccionado.css('display','none');
        }else{//Si se deja de seleccionar, que retorne a sus valores anteriores
            valorSeleccionado.css('display','inline');
        }

     })
```

la idea es que al seleccionar un divY tenga esos valores css, pero que al seleccionar un divX me retorne os valores del divY y así sucesivamente con el resto de los divs.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Quieres que al hacer clic en `divX` se haga qué exactamente, explicado de la forma más simple posible?

Comment: vale. Si selecciono un `divX`, este se va a ocultar: (display,none). Ahora si seleccion un `divY` este se va a ocultar: (display,none) y el `divX` se va a mostrar: (display,inline). Ahora si selecciono un `divZ` se va a ocultar: (display,none) y el `divX` y `divY` se van a mostrar. En pocas palabras, al dar click en UNO de los divs, debe de ocultarse (display,none), pero el resto de los divs no, deben quedar con los valores anteriores (display,inline)

Comment: O sea, explicado simplemente: cuando se selecciona un div que se oculten los otros, punto.

Comment: Sí, exacto. Te agredecería si tienes alguna solucion para esto porfa :)

Comment: Falta un detalle sobre cómo funciona eso en el contexto. Dinos ¿cómo se muestran los divs de entrada? ¿Cómo se deselecciona el div seleccionado y qué pasa cuando ese div se deselecciona? Quizá conviene que expliques un poco lo que quieres hacer, porque es que realmente no le veo sentido a lo que quieres implementar aquí.

Comment: todos los divs comienzan con un display:inline y cuando se selecciona uno, con el $(this), este se cambia por un display:none, pero hasta ahí me quedé, porque no sé cómo hacer para que un div quede en display:inline y el resto quede se devuelva a su valor que es display:inline

Comment: Hay que tratar de explicar los problemas con sencillez, y basándote en como funciona en la realidad. Veamos: de entrada los tres divs se muestran. Se hace clic en uno cualquiera de los tres ... Los otros dos deben ocultarse. ¿He entendido bien hasta ahí? Ahora pregunto, ¿qué sigue? Tenemos un div visible y los otros dos no se ven ... sigue explicando el contexto. Por ejemplo, ¿qué acción puede ocurrir ahora y qué debería ocurrir cuando esa acción ocurra?

Comment: pues, un ejemplo clarisimo es como las pestañas de los navegadores. cuando uno selecciona uno se muestra que está activo y el resto no, [0,0,0,1] [0,1,0,0]